# TreeMap removing all keys greater than a certain key

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, treemap

In a project I need to remove all objects having key value greater than a certain key (key type is `Date`, if it matters).

As far as I know `TreeMap` implemented in Java is a red-black tree which is a binary search tree. So I should get `O(n)` when removing a subtree.
But I can't find any method to do this other than making a tail view and remove one by one, which takes `O(logn)`.

Any good ideas implementing this function? I believe treeMap is the correct dataStructure to use and should be able to do this.

thanks in advance

Comment: *Non sequitur.* The fact that it's a red-black tree doesn't mean you can remove a subtree in O(N).

Comment: What is N ? (N=lg(n) ) ?  The question is about removing it in O(lg(n)) not O(n)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quite simple. Instead of removing the entries one-by-one, use `Map.clear()` to remove the elements. In code:

```
map.tailMap(key).clear();
```

Comment: This would remove the subtree, more or less?

Comment: @Tyler The title says "removing all keys greater than a certain key", and that's what this does.

Comment: But will it run in *O(N)* time? *That's* the question.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this with a `SortedMap`?

Comment: That's not the question either. The question is how to do it in O(N). The answer may well be that you can't.

Comment: @EJP from the source code it seems clearing is just setting root=NULL, so including GC runtime, it should be O(N) if fixAfterDeletion is called only once.. I will do an experiment on this.

Comment: @tbodt Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand how the opertaion on tailMap will callback the origin map. Will it call the fixAfterDeletion function of the origin map after clearing?

Comment: @HongxiangQiu That's the code for clearing the entire tree. Clearing a subtree is elsewhere in the code, and it can't be just a matter of setting root to null, as the red-black properties have to be preserved. There must be rotations.

Comment: @EJP yes you are right. i didnt look into the return type which is a sub*tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TreeMapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // creating maps
            TreeMap<Integer, String> treemap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
            SortedMap<Integer, String> treemapincl = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

            // populating tree map
            treemap.put(2, "two");
            treemap.put(1, "one");
            treemap.put(3, "three");
            treemap.put(6, "six");
            treemap.put(5, "five");

            System.out.println("Getting tail map");
            treemap.tailMap(3).clear();

            System.out.println("Tail map values: " + treemapincl);
            System.out.println("Tree map values: " + treemap);
     }
}
```

This will remove the elements in the tree map.